# iOS: Earlgrey/Detox error after running the same test twice

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, e2e-testing, earlgrey, detox

Running the same test twice fails the second time.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

This test passes:

```js
describe('Login', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should not login', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id('welcome')))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(5000);

    await element(by.id('EmailField')).clearText();
    await element(by.id('EmailField')).typeText('wronggmail.com');
    await element(by.id('PasswordField')).clearText();
    await element(by.id('PasswordField')).typeText('wrongpass');

    await element(by.id('LoginButton')).tap();

    await waitFor(element(by.id('Home')))
      .toBeNotVisible()
      .withTimeout(10000);
  });
});
```

This fails:

```js
describe('Login', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await device.reloadReactNative();
  });

  it('should not login', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id('welcome')))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(5000);

    await element(by.id('EmailField')).typeText('wronggmail.com');
    await element(by.id('PasswordField')).typeText('wrongpass');

    await element(by.id('LoginButton')).tap();

    await waitFor(element(by.id('Home')))
      .toBeNotVisible()
      .withTimeout(10000);
  });

  it('should not login', async () => {
    await waitFor(element(by.id('welcome')))
      .toBeVisible()
      .withTimeout(5000);

    await element(by.id('EmailField')).typeText('wronggmail.com');
    await element(by.id('PasswordField')).typeText('wrongpass');

    await element(by.id('LoginButton')).tap();

    await waitFor(element(by.id('Home')))
      .toBeNotVisible()
      .withTimeout(10000);
  });
});
```

**Detox, Node, Device, Xcode and macOS Versions**

```
$ yarn list --depth=0 | grep 'detox@\| jest@'
├─ detox@5.10.0
├─ jest@21.2.1

$ node --version
v8.9.0

$ xcodebuild -version
Xcode 9.1
Build version 9B55

$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.12.6
```

- Device: iPhone 6 iOS 11.1 (simulator)

**Device and verbose Detox logs**

```
$ npm run test-e2e

> myRN@0.0.1 test-e2e /Users/gianfranco/temp/myRN
> jest e2e --setupTestFrameworkScriptFile=./e2e/init.js --bail

 server listening on localhost:51830...
 : Launching ...
6: The stdout and stderr logs were recreated, you can watch them with:
        tail -F $HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C8A0B6F9-5751-4C97-8069-0288C7F928B8/data/tmp/detox.last_launch_app_log.{out,err}
 FAIL  e2e/Login.spec.js (15.641s)
  Login
    ✓ should not login (7616ms)
    ✕ should not login (1639ms)

  ● Login › should not login

    Error: An action failed. Please refer to the error trace below.
    Exception with Action: {
      "Action Name" : "Clear text",
      "Element Matcher" : "(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('EmailField')) && !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))) || (kindOfClass('UIScrollView') && ((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('EmailField')) && kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))))))"
    }

    Error Trace: [
      {
        "Description" : "First responder [F] of element [E] does not conform to UITextInput protocol.",
        "Description Glossary" :     {
          "F" : "<RCTRootView: 0x7fd5b7c13d90; frame = (0 0; 375 667); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x60800003da40>>",
          "E" : "<RCTUITextField: 0x7fd5b8876000; baseClass = UITextField; frame = (0 0; 375 36); text = 'hello@gmail.com'; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000241bf0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000238080>>"
        },
        "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
        "Error Code" : "2",
        "File Name" : "GREYActions.m",
        "Function Name" : "+[GREYActions grey_actionForTypeText:atUITextPosition:]_block_invoke",
        "Line" : "547"
      }
    ]

      at Client._callee8$ (node_modules/detox/lib/client/Client.js:58:19)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:337:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:96:21)
      at step (node_modules/detox/lib/client/Client.js:1:836)
      at node_modules/detox/lib/client/Client.js:1:1035
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15
      at flush (node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        15.713s
Ran all test suites matching /e2e/i.
```

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Comment: Not too sure about this one but how about waiting for the field to be visible in the test that fails:
    await expect(element(by.id('EmailField'))).toBeVisible();

Or maybe trying a .tap() on it before going for the .typeText().

Comment: @Nemoverflow that was it! the keyboard was doing something strange. doing `.tap()` before `typeText()` worked! thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Nemoverflow  do you mind posting that as answer so that this question gets resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this one in answer form as asked. Sorry for the delay.

Try going for a .tap() before going for the .typeText().

```
[...]
await expect(element(by.id('EmailField'))).toBeVisible();
await element(by.id('EmailField')).tap();
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the keyboard activated I had that issue.

When clicked on the simulator, toggles keyboard on input tap.

> command + k